# First Hitting Time and Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, monte-carlo

I am interested in implementing a Monte Carlo simulation in Python of a first hitting time (first passage time) of an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process (or similar). Specifically interested in fatter tails distributions but that is only a bonus.

I would be grateful if someone could point me towards some resources.

Comment: Estimating hitting time by MC simulation can be tricky. The simulation is perforce in discrete time, but the true process is continuous and can cross the barrier "in between" the times when the simulation looks at things. This can cause a delay in recognizing that the process has crossed the barrier, and also can miss a brief foray above the barrier if the process soon returns to below the barrier. It is important to consider this issue.

Comment: @noob2 that is a good point. Would you recommend another non-probabilistic method?

Comment: @noob2, true what you say. What about making the Euler-Maruyama discretization step smaller and smaller the nearest we are to the boundary? This should increase the accuracy estimation while keeping the computational burden under control for far "regions".

Comment: I like your idea!